# ideavim (mac): On doing a paste in normal mode (press `p`), cursor jumps to previous location in editor after pasting

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

On enabling ideavim plugin (on Mac), while doing a paste operation in normal mode of vim by pressing `p`, the paste happens but the cursor jumps to the previous location in the editor. This previous location could even be in another file (something similar to Intellij command `Cmd+[`).

I tried to see if there is a keymap clash with ideavim vs. intellij, but could not find one.

Can this be fixed by changing some keymap entry.. or some option in the Preferences?

Comment: Don't you have conflicting mappings in `~/.ideavimrc`?

Comment: All it contains is `set showmode`